# how to model inheritance in object oriented programming

Tags: java, parent

suppose there is a parent class and 3 child classes.If there's a method which needs to be included in two of the child classes where to place it?

Comment: perhaps what you really have is a grandparent with two children one of which has two grandchildren.

Answer (score 2):

I say the structure has to be like this

```
    Parent
    |    |
Child   ChildTwo
        |       |
ChildTwoFirst   ChildTwoSecond
```

Here ChildTwo class will have your added method.
Hope that might help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In the child classes which need it, either directly or by defining an intermediate super class for the two specific children which inherits from the parent. If the method cannot be invoked on the parent, or on all of its children, it doesn't belong in the parent.